# i want to use the result of two different routers in one router in express js

Tags: node.js, express

I have two different routers and both gives the accurate result in case of separate views. But i want to get the both result in one View (Index). 
here is the first Router:

```
router.get('/', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => { 
  if(req.query.search){
  const regex = new RegExp(escapeRegex(req.query.search), 'gi');
  Idea.find({itemName: regex}, function(err, ideas){
  if(err){
        console.log(err);
      }
      else{
        res.render('ideas/index', {
          ideas:ideas
        });
      }
    });
  } 
  else {
    Idea.find({})
    .sort({date:'desc'})
    .then(ideas => {
      res.render('ideas/index',{
        ideas:ideas
      });
    });
  }
});
```

and here is the second one.

```
router.get("/sumResult", function(req, res) {
    var itemPrice = req.params.itemPrice;
    var isSolved = function(itemPrice, callback){ 
      console.log("in the aggregation: ", itemPrice);
      Idea.aggregate([
        //var isSolved = User.aggregate([
          {$group: {
            _id: null,
            totalPrice: { $sum: "$itemPrice" },
            total: {$sum: 1}  
          }}
    ],
    function(err, idea){
        console.log("this is the result: ", idea); // logs a result if the there is one, and [] if there is no result.
        callback(err, idea); // <<=== call callback here to return
    });
    };

  isSolved(itemPrice, function(err, idea) {
    if (err) {
      return def.reject(err);
    } else {
      res.render('ideas/sumResult', {
        idea:idea
      });
    }
  }); 
});
```

I am struggling hard to get the both results in one but unable to do this i am a beginner to node.

Answer (score 0):

The 'usual' or 'correct' way to handle this would be to have a separate function for what you want. For example, you want to call route A from route B and render both data. What I would do is:

```
let something = () =>{
 // Do stuff
}
```

Route A:

```
router.get('/',(req,res)=>{
  something();
})
```

Route B:

```
router.get('/other',(req,res)=>{
  //Do stuff
  something(); // get result
  render();
})
```

**This is not a complete solution but just an Idea.**